# Azure Computer Vision APIs Returns default values

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm currently using the Computer Vision API to get image dimensions and also to detect color & adult content.

The API returns back the correct metadata containing the width, height, and format, but all the values for Color or Adult Content come back as default values (zeros/null/false/"None").

If it makes any difference, I'm calling the service in US West which is listed as having these features enabled. Also, I specify that I want these features in the request, which is why I receive the objects for these two features.

How do I get this information to be populated accordingly?

Example request I just used with today's Bing image. I'm using the `Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision` package from nuget which contains the `AnalyzeImageAsync` method.

```
POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze? 
visualFeatures=Adult%2CColor HTTP/1.1
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <REMOVED>
User-Agent: FxVersion/4.6.26515.07 Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.ComputerVisionAPI/1.1.0.0
x-ms-request-root-id: 5e7823bb-4cac1f594af57fcf
x-ms-request-id: |5e7823bb-4cac1f594af57fcf.2.
Request-Id: |5e7823bb-4cac1f594af57fcf.2.
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 129
Host: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

{
"url": "https://outerpulsemedia.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/images/0be893af-9edc-416a-a779-929d2e2d1428-1529100079.jpg"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "adult": {
        "isAdultContent": false,
        "adultScore": 0.0,
        "isRacyContent": false,
        "racyScore": 0.0
    },
    "color": {
        "dominantColorForeground": "None",
        "dominantColorBackground": "None",
        "dominantColors": [],
        "accentColor": "000000",
        "isBwImg": false
    },
    "requestId": "5b57186d-9976-4af7-97fd-e06b33fb0ecb",
    "metadata": {
        "height": 1200,
        "width": 1920,
        "format": "Jpeg"
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using the make the request?  What does the request look like, exactly?

Comment: Also, are you able to share the image?

Comment: I've update the post question with this information.

Comment: I had a quick look and got the same problem using West Europe API and your image (https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa/console). But when using other images, I got results (PNG or JPG files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPEG image is not, strictly speaking, correctly encoded.  Specifically the `EOI` (end of image) marker is missing.  The image should end with `FF D9`, whereas your image is ending simply in `FF`.  This is why the image classifier is returning default values instead of true values.

While a case could be made that either the (a) return response is deceptive, or (b) the API should have returned a 400 Bad Request, it is probably more beneficial for you to try and understand how the image got truncated by a byte.

Comment: The image was the issue here. The true problem was an upload client that put the image into blob storage which trimmed the ending character. It would be nice if there was some explicit error here so that my service can reject the image due to failed analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the details, is there a way to check this encoding?